# Android-How prevent manual installation of android application

Tags: android

I have an application A that launches an intent to install application B(which is present in app A's data folder).

Once application B is installed, file managers like ASTRO can backup Application B's apk file.

So I want to prevent the user from manually installing it(say if he clicks on the backup apk file of Application B it should not install).

Is there a way to disable manual installation...?

Answer (score 1):

But there are two ways to monitor the app.one is, you can use File Observer to

monitor the apps. whenever the apps been taken as back up do stuffs to prevent it. Another way is

For eg: if it's storing in sdcard\am\ use like this.

```
    File f=new File("\mnt\sdcard\am\abc.apk");// file location of your app
    {
       if(f.exists)
       {
           f.delete();
       }
    }
```

For File Observer,have a glance of this.It might help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: I cant say it's not possible. Because few months ago, i try to take backup for an apps by using several android apps(Astro,ESfilexplorer and android mate) .It says backup not possible. May be file observer might used or above stuffs used in it or it may also used some other hardcoded using proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the location where the backup is taken and delete the apk.

If APk is available to the file manager then it can open it and install it, I am not aware of any way to stop it as its out of your application scope.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on AOSP Android.

The Install from unknown sources option is a setting in `Settings.Global` (previously in `Settings.Secure`) and cannot be controlled by third party applications.

However, it is possible do achieve this if you're willing to modify and compile Android itself for each and every device you want to use this on, as is done by AT&T on some of their devices.

The best you can do is try to find the backup file and delete it if you have access to that part of the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's feasible, but I would solve this by having application `A` spit out a code that has to be manually entered (like a two step verification) on application `B` is installed, and then verify it server side. So that way the rogue install like you mentioned would be rendered useless. Maybe you could pop up an error to the user informing them of this.